# Make HTML link from first $value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am executing a SQL query where I want the value of the first column of every row to be a link.

This is my code:

```
$select_rma_detail = $dbh->prepare (
    "SELECT rd_rma_nr, rd_artikel_code, rd_serienr, rd_ontvangenklant, 
    rd_onder_waarborg, rd_omr_rep, rd_teruggestuurdklant, rd_afgehandelklant
    FROM rma_detail 
    LEFT JOIN rma ON rma_detail.rd_rma_id=rma.r_id
    LEFT JOIN klanten ON rma.r_klantid=klanten.k_id WHERE k_id = ?"
);
$select_rma_detail->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['k_id']);
$select_rma_detail->execute();


while ($selectrmarow = $selectrmadetail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) {
        $value =($value == 1) ? 'JA' : $value;
        echo "<td>$value</td>"; 
    }
}
```

This is a dump of my array now:

```
array(8) { 
    ["rd_rma_nr"]=> string(9) "201405022"
    ["rd_artikel_code"]=> string(7) "34-CXN3"
    ["rd_serienr"]=> string(13) "5411284116133"
    ["rd_ontvangenklant"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["rd_onder_waarborg"]=> NULL
    ["rd_omr_rep"]=> NULL
    ["rd_teruggestuurdklant"]=> NULL
    ["rd_afgehandelklant"]=> NULL 
}
array(8) {
    ["rd_rma_nr"]=> string(9) "201405023"
    ["rd_artikel_code"]=> string(7) "51-EQP1"
    ["rd_serienr"]=> string(13) "5411284116133"
    ["rd_ontvangenklant"]=> NULL
    ["rd_onder_waarborg"]=> NULL
    ["rd_omr_rep"]=> NULL
    ["rd_teruggestuurdklant"]=> NULL
    ["rd_afgehandelklant"]=> NULL
}
array(8) {
    ["rd_rma_nr"]=> string(10) "2014050712"
    ["rd_artikel_code"]=> string(7) "72-BMM3"
    ["rd_serienr"]=> string(7) "4599489"
    ["rd_ontvangenklant"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["rd_onder_waarborg"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["rd_omr_rep"]=> string(8) "OMRUILEN"
    ["rd_teruggestuurdklant"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["rd_afgehandelklant"]=> string(1) "1"
}
array(8) {
    ["rd_rma_nr"]=> string(10) "2014051113"
    ["rd_artikel_code"]=> string(7) "34-CXN3"
    ["rd_serienr"]=> string(5) "11111"
    ["rd_ontvangenklant"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["rd_onder_waarborg"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["rd_omr_rep"]=> string(8) "OMRUILEN"
    ["rd_teruggestuurdklant"]=> NULL
    ["rd_afgehandelklant"]=> NULL 
}
```

How can I put the `rd_tma_nr` into a link `<a></a>` so I can make a detail page containing all of the info of that RMA NUMBER? I know how to do it if I write it without the foreach but is it possible to do it with foreach?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your foreach statement:

```
foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) 
{
    if($key=='rd_rma_nr')
    {
        echo "<td><a href='something.blahblahblah?something=somethingelse'>$value</a></td>"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $value =($value == 1) ? 'JA' : $value;
        echo "<td>$value</td>"; 
    }
}
```

You are already returning an ASSOC_ARRAY which means you have the column names. You can make a simple if statement to see if the column name is the one you want to make a link of - and if so, make the link, otherwise use a normal setting for it.

You could also do a switch statement based on the field if you wanted to make many different options such as:

```
foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) 
{
    switch($key)
    {
        case 'rd_rma_nr':
            echo "<td><a href='something.blahblahblah?something=somethingelse'>$value</a></td>"; 
            break;
        case 'rd_artikel_code'
            echo "<td><a href='something2.blah?somethingElse=$value'>$value</a></td>";
            break;
        default:
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
}
```

Edit: Update your select query:

Your query only selects one column called `rd_rma_nr` but if i had multiples, you can alias the selection like this:

```
SELECT 
    rd_rma_nr, 
    rd_rma_nr as rd_rma_nr2, 
    rd_artikel_code, 
    rd_serienr, 
    rd_ontvangenklant, 
    rd_onder_waarborg, 
    rd_omr_rep, 
    rd_teruggestuurdklant, 
    rd_afgehandelklant 
FROM 
    rma_detail 
        LEFT JOIN rma 
            ON rma_detail.rd_rma_id=rma.r_id 
        LEFT JOIN klanten 
            ON rma.r_klantid=klanten.k_id 
WHERE k_id = ?
```

which would then return it into the assoc array as a different name.

Edit:

If you only want to link the first row that contains the field `rd_rma_nr` then you can perform a simple bool comparison in your foreach like this:

```
$hasLinked=false;
foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) 
{
    if($key=='rd_rma_nr' && $hasLinked==false)
    {
        echo "<td><a href='something.blahblahblah?something=somethingelse'>$value</a></td>"; 
        $hasLinked=true;
    }
    else
    {
        $value =($value == 1) ? 'JA' : $value;
        echo "<td>$value</td>"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for everyone, but still not working 100% because now i have 2 times the rd_rma_nr in my table (1st and 2nd column). To be honest my first idea was in that way but than i already realized this problem with the double columns. I've already tried to add unset($selectrmarow['rd_rma_nr']); in front of the else but still no luck

Comment: @Raz3rt The edit you made is not a print_r of your PDO:Fetch, it is a print_r of your entire recordset. There isn't anything in the query you posted that will return such an array for each row. Why are you showing an array if there isn't anything in your code that is appending rows from the database to an array? It is almost like you are running a fetchall instead of a fetch?

Comment: Maybe my question here above isn't so clear yet. When i now look at my table i see the rd_rma_nr two times and that i want to avoid. I only want to see it into a link.

Comment: it would be nice to have some help with what you mean. Its hard to understand and till in my learning course the only thing i ever used is ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). What i have posted above is just a var_dump and not a print_r. Hope this helps?

Comment: In other words isn't the $selectrmarow allready an array? Or do i have to make different arrays from the rows doing this: array[] = $selectrmarow?

Comment: @Raz3rt the FETCH PDO option returns a single row of data at a time, which you should traverse, parse, do whatever you like with (inside the foreach) - then do the same for the next and so on and so on. FETCH_ALL is generally a bad idea as it can lead to huge memory use if you mistakenly fetch too many rows. I would always suggest running through each individual row (and applying logic as needed) before moving on to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your help now i understand! Because of my while loop it is like you do a fetchall(). If i remove the while loop it only shows one row at a time. I think i know what to do next!

Answer (score 3):

```
while($selectrmarow = $selectrmadetail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "rd_tma_nr") {
            $value = "<a href='detail.php?id=".$value."'>Details of ".$value."</a>";
        }
        echo "<td>$value</td>"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use mysql's inbuilt functionality "concat" for this. like this

```
$select_rma_detail = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT 
    concat('<a>',rd_rma_nr,'</a>'), 
    rd_artikel_code, 
    rd_serienr, 
    rd_ontvangenklant, 
    rd_onder_waarborg, 
    rd_omr_rep, 
    rd_teruggestuurdklant, 
    rd_afgehandelklant 
FROM 
    rma_detail 
LEFT JOIN rma ON 
    rma_detail.rd_rma_id=rma.r_id 
LEFT JOIN klanten ON 
    rma.r_klantid=klanten.k_id 
WHERE 
    k_id = ?");
```

UPDATE:- 
You can always change the query as your requirement , like this :-

$select_rma_detail = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT 
    concat(concat('') ,rd_rma_nr,''), 
    rd_artikel_code, 
    rd_serienr, 
    rd_ontvangenklant, 
    rd_onder_waarborg, 
    rd_omr_rep, 
    rd_teruggestuurdklant, 
    rd_afgehandelklant 
FROM 
    rma_detail 
LEFT JOIN rma ON 
    rma_detail.rd_rma_id=rma.r_id 
LEFT JOIN klanten ON 
    rma.r_klantid=klanten.k_id 
WHERE 
    k_id = ?");

NOTE:- "primary_key" is the column name of which you want the value.

Comment: Could be an option if it wasn't a dynamic link. I want to make my header look like this: index.php?page=rma-detail&id=2014052017 so my id has to contain the value of that rd_rma_nr and on the section my value is still empty because the query isn't executed yet

Comment: please check this for query "SELECT concat(concat('<a href="',primary_key,'">') ,rd_rma_nr,'</a>')"

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$cnt=0;
foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) {
  $cnt+=1;
  if($cnt==1)
  {
      echo "<td><a>".$value."</a></td>";
  }  
  else
  {
      echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
  }  

}
```

**Update 2 :**

```
foreach ($selectrmarow as $key => $value) {
  if($key=="rd_rma_nr")
  {
      echo "<td><a href='some_link'>".$value."</a></td>";
  }  
  else
  {
      echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
  }  

}
```

Comment: As the OP is already getting the key from the assoc array, you would be better to check the name of the column being returned rather than using the first column being returned.

Comment: Which makes it no different to the answer I provided really though does it? :(